# Flutter firebase_messaging support for apns

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing firebase_messaging in flutter app. Our backend uses APN for iOS push. On device I am able to get the APN token through getAPNSToken().
Now if I send push through APN and not FCM to iOS device, will firebase_messaging plugin be able to handle that, invoking all callbacks (onMessage, onMessageOpenedApp etc.).

APN sample payload :

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "body": "this is body",
      "title": "title"
    }
  }
}
```